# Sylius/Symfony cache compile error

Tags: symfony, sylius, doctrine-phpcr

I have the following error after update a sylius project from 0.15 to 0.17. Also the Jackalope\Session::getNode method fails and throw a timeout error, the consumption of cpu and memory of this method is very high.

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/srv/kulashare/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SyliusComponentUserModelUser.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:')" at
>   /srv/kulashare/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   line 209 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0):
>   Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/srv/kulashare/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SyliusComponentUserModelUser.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') at
>   /srv/kulashare/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209)"}
>   []

Answer (score 2):

This happens, when your doctrine-relations to the user-table use the wrong UserModel-Entity:

Instead of

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\User\Model\User", cascade={"persist"})
```

you should use:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\User", cascade={"persist"})
```

The difference here is the Namespace Sylius\Component\Core vs Sylius\Component\User